# Formula for the number of carries when multiplying two numbers

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Kummer's theorem allows for giving the number of carries when two numbers are added in a prime base. Is there an analogous theorem giving the number of carries when two numbers are multiplied?

I assume there is a similar way to extend Kummer's theorem so I'm expecting it to be related to the p-adic valuation and that's why I'm tagging it that way.